# Form->control('fecha')

Tags: cakephp

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con CakePHP 3 a la hora de crear un control de tipo date, y que tenga el formato de ingreso D M Y.
Ya que ahora me queda Y M D H i.

Por lo que veo, el option 'dateFormat' no funciona.
Sí saben como resolver este problemilla se los agredecería!

```
echo $this->Form->control('fecha_nacimiento', ['label' => 'Fecha de nacimiento', 'empty' => false, ' dateFormat' => 'DMY','separator' =>
                    null, 'error' => false, 'minYear' => date('Y') - 70, 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 5 ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la forma para solucionar el problemilla!

```
<?php
    $this->Form->templates(['dateWidget' => '{{day}}{{month}}{{year}}']);

    echo $this->Form->control('fecha_nacimiento', ['label' => 'Fecha de nacimiento', 'empty' => false, 'type' => 'date' ,'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'minYear' => date('Y') - 70, 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 5 ]);

?>
```